# How to start dialogframent from dialogfragment properly?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I start dialog fragment B from dialog fragment A

```
CreateNewPlayListDialog newPlayListDialog = new CreateNewPlayListDialog();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("id", videoId);
                    newPlayListDialog.setArguments(b);
                    newPlayListDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog_new_playlist");
```

And thats works. However firstDialogFragment is not cancelled.
If I try

```
CreateNewPlayListDialog newPlayListDialog = new CreateNewPlayListDialog();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("id", videoId);
                    newPlayListDialog.setArguments(b);
                    newPlayListDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog_new_playlist");
                    PlayListChooserDialog.this.dismiss();
```

Then dialogfragment B starts and is cancelled imidiatly and Dialog A remain;

How to start dialog B from dialog Am such as dialog A will be cancelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment dismissal is a mere wrapper of removing last fragment from the stack.

Please swap the last two lines as:

```
PlayListChooserDialog.this.dismiss();
newPlayListDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog_new_playlist");
```

If you get exceptions (depends what is the rest of the code doing), then safest way is reaching a method in your activity directly and load the other fragment from there, e.g.

```
public final ApplicationActivity extends Activity {
    public void onDialog(String whichOne) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(whichOne) {
            return;
        }
        if (whichOne.equals.PlayListDialog.NAME) {
            newPlayListDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog_new_playlist");
        }
        else if(...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public final PlayListDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String NAME = PlayListDIalog.class.getSimpleName();
    ...
}
```

Then in you code where you dismiss fragment A

```
((ApplicationActivity) getActivity()).onDialog(PlayListDialog.NAME);
 PlayListChooserDialog.this.dismiss();
```

Comment: swapping did not help

Comment: redirecting result of first dialog to activity and start new dialog from activity did help